# Cannot access Windows because either Ubuntu deleted my C: drive content or it simply decided to not show Windows 10 in the grub loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

### Cannot access Windows 10. Think Ubuntu just changed from D: drive partition to C: drive ( the entire thing).

I officially think I've lost Windows 10 due to Ubuntu. I set a new partition for the entirety of my Windows and Games specified drive, C: drive AKA SSD. I checked through fdisk I think it was and there was only 500 MB of data being used on my SSD, so I assume my entire Windows is lost. By the way, I was attempting to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, didn't work out the way it was supposed to, or like it does in videos/tutorials.

Edit:
    `sudo update-grub`
worked like a charm.

Any clues? Help.

Specs:
GTX 1070 MSI,
i7 6700K,
16GB RAM.

If you need anything else, including specs or even just me to type in some commands in terminal, please leave a comment, you guys are my last resort before a clean installation of Windows 10.

Specific Terminal Commands Requested -

DF -

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5       48173944 3776008  41927744   9% /
udev               10240       0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs            3286288    9328   3276960   1% /run
tmpfs            8215716     156   8215560   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8215716       0   8215716   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            1643144       8   1643136   1% /run/user/117
tmpfs            1643144       8   1643136   1% /run/user/1000
```

Sudo LSBLK -F:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL           UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                
├─sda1 ntfs   System Reserved 30D23E29D23DF3A6                     
└─sda2 ntfs   SSD             D4DA44CBDA44AC14                     
sdb                                                                
├─sdb1 ntfs   HDD             EC6C8EC76C8E8C50                     
├─sdb2                                                             
├─sdb5 ext4                   95f78595-80cc-45ac-bb96-b1ae8b6d3fba /
└─sdb6 swap                   bc7e64e1-2700-421a-b3bc-06925bb4da98 [SWAP]
sr0
```

Sudo LSBLK -M:

```
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda    223.6G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   500M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda2 223.1G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb      1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb1   1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb2     1K root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdb5  46.8G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb6     2G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0     1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
```

Sudo Parted -LS:

```
Model: ATA KINGSTON SUV400S (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  525MB  524MB  primary  ntfs         boot
2      525MB   240GB  240GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA WDC WD20EARX-00P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1948GB  1948GB  primary   ntfs            boot
 2      1948GB  2000GB  52.4GB  extended
 5      1948GB  1998GB  50.3GB  logical   ext4
 6      1998GB  2000GB  2174MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

ATA KINGSTON SUV400S Is my SSD.

Comment: Please edit the following command lines *including all the output text from them* into your question: `df` , `sudo lsblk -f` , `sudo lsblk -m` , `sudo parted -ls`. Indent four spaces to make it interpreted as `code`. It will help us help you.

Comment: Completed that, all information added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have MSDOS partition tables and no EFI partition. So you have installed Windows 10 in BIOS mode. And now you have installed Ubuntu into the root partition `/dev/sdb5` and the swap partition `/dev/sdb6`. There are still several partitions left with the NTFS file system:

- The whole drive /dev/sda seems untouched by Ubuntu. This is the SSD. (Maybe there is a 'grub' bootloader for Ubuntu.)
- The partition /dev/sdb1 is a big partition with NTFS, and it has a boot flag.

There is hope that your Windows is still there, and the only problem is that Ubuntu does not see it.

The reason you don't see Windows via Ubuntu might be, that Windows is *hibernated* or semi-hibernated alias uses *fast startup*. This leaves the file system in a state that should not be touched by other operating systems, and Ubuntu stays away from them, and does not see Windows. I am no Windows expert, but I know there are solutions (if this is the problem).

One solution is to repair the Windows bootloader. It means that the Ubuntu bootloader 'grub' will be overwritten, but after turning off fast startup you can re-install grub and it should recognize Windows and show a line for it in the boot menu. This would give you a convenient dual boot system.

Another solution is to try to fix it from Ubuntu. I have never done that, so I will not recommend that method, but I would welcome someone who knows, to show how to do it that way.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I found this link browsing for 'repair windows 10 bootloader in bios mode' (without quotes),  http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows You might find better links, there are many help pages for this and similar problem.

Comment: I cannot use that what so ever, I spam F8, yet it brings me to grub, where my only option is Debian. Bump.

Comment: Issue fixed, worked like a charm!
    sudo update-grub

Comment: Congratulations! I'm glad you found a solution :-)